# Using static global or inline variable - which would be more efficient?

Tags: java, static, jit

I have a question regarding JIT (is this the right one to address?)

For example I have a simple math task to do and I would not know which would be the better way to program it:

```
public class Spielwiese {

    static final BigDecimal STATIC_VALUE = new BigDecimal( "5" );

    public static BigDecimal doSomeCalculation1(BigDecimal bd) {
        return new BigDecimal("5").multiply( bd );
    }

    public static BigDecimal doSomeCalculation2(BigDecimal bd) {
        return STATIC_VALUE.multiply( bd );
    }
}
```

Would the running java program see that the *new BigDecimal("5")* instruction actually could be replaced by a static usage? - That would probably make **doSomeCalculation1(...)** more readable.

If not, what would be other reasons to repeat the instantiating of the same/equal value over and over?

How do You do it, personally?

Where else could I have gotten an answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a JIT question.  The difference between the two versions of the code is a effectively about caching.

- In one version, you consume more space in the long term because `STATIC_VALUE` is reachable for the lifetime of the `Spielwiese` class: probably the application.
- In the other version, you construct and then discard an extra `BigDecimal` object each time the method is called.

This will be the case irrespective of JIT compilation.

---

Which would I do?

First off, unless my intuition told me that the performance is likely to *matter*, I would probably optimize for readability.  This kind of micro-optimization is rarely worthwhile from the programmer productivity perspective.

If I needed to optimize for the case where the method is called frequently, the `STATIC_VALUE` approach is (IMO) likely to be a bit faster.  A reference to a `static` variable is as single bytecode and is likely to translate to a single machine instruction.  (Or maybe two).  Construction a new `BigDecimal` value will take orders of magnitude more instructions.

If I needed to optimize for memory usage, it is debatable which would be better.   However, the difference between the two approaches is likely to be so small that it is difficult to actually measure.

---

> Where else could I have gotten an answer to my question?

You could get answer yourself:

- by creating a benchmark and measuring, or
- by using the JVM option that outputs the JIT-compiled code ... and analyzing the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting answer!

I somewhat have in my mind that the JIT would magically see the instantiation of the same BigDecimal(5) over and over and then smartly say,  that it could be done statically. This would target me for programming for readability.